# Windows 7: unable to copy-paste directory path in "Save File As" dialogue box

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, ssms, save-as

I am attempting to save a `.sql` file from Sql Server Management Studio to a non-default directory location. I would like to be able to copy the directory path from an open `Explorer` window and paste it into the `Save File As` dialogue box. However, from SSMS, it appears the only option is to navigate to the desired folder through the GUI. Even selecting the `Save in:` dropdown and beginning to type just activates the GUI & associated hotkeys.

In other applications ( Excel for example ), it is possible to type or copy-paste a full directory path. Is this a setting I can toggle in SSMS?

**I am not trying to change the default save location.** I am attempting to speed up folder navigation when saving files from SSMS.

Is it possible to get the `Save As` ( Excel ) style box rather than the `Save File As` style dialogue box in SSMS?

**Ssms Save File As dialogue ( bad )**

[image: http://i.imgur.com/8RjES5c.png]

**Excel Save As dialogue ( good )**

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Kq4MBk3.png]

Comment: the application has to support the new Vista style dialogs. Now all do this. Which  Sql Server Management Studio version do you use?

Comment: @magicandre1981 - I use SSMS 2008 R2. Do I need to upgrade to a more recent version to get this functionality?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have just verified with another user in my office that SSMS 2012 provides this functionality. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Excel SaveAs Dialog uses the new Vista style dialogs. The [applications has to implement the new dialogs](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/Windows-Vista-for-Developers-_1320_-Part-6-_1320_-The-New-File-Dialogs) to support it. In your cause it must support [IFileSaveDialog](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16678/Vista-Goodies-in-C-Using-the-New-Vista-File-Dialog) which seams not to be done by your older version. Update to the most recent version.